# .prepend() with .show(effect) issue

Tags: jquery

Creating a `.prepend()` function. It prepends and then shows the div correct - as it should. However, the `.show()` effect (i.e. scale) isn't executing. Is this even possible? I know there's limitations with .append() and .prepend().

And yes, I'm pointing to jQuery's UI script.

```
$('<div class="load-success" style=display:none"></div>').prependTo('.body-img-deets').show("scale", {}, 900);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a " before display: none ? Anyway, try hiding it and then showing it.

```
$('<div class="load-success" />').prependTo('.body-img-deets')
                                 .hide()
                                 .show("scale", {}, 900);
```

Comment: aghhhh...duh!! IDE can't pick up source errors in .append()...missed this. Thanks!